# Flutter bottomNavigationBar under put row section

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm a beginner in the flutter, Im added my flutter page to bottomNavigationBar: Container to button  and i want to to put under bottom button to this section
like this my  image

```
  Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        RichText(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                            TextSpan(
                                text: "Already have an account?",
                                style: TextStyle(color: m_titleColor,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontFamily: "regular")),
                            TextSpan(
                                text: " Sign in",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color:  Color(0xFF2A3476),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    fontFamily: "medium")),
                          ]),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
```

any idea how can i put it correctly ?
Thanks

import 'dart:ui';

```
import 'package:cmapp/widgets/components/alert.dart';
import 'package:cmapp/widgets/theme/constants.dart';
import 'package:cmapp/widgets/theme/constants.dart';
import 'package:cmapp/widgets/theme/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpScreenState createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State< SignUpScreen > {
  //validation controller
  TextEditingController fNameController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lNameController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nickNameController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController phoneController = new TextEditingController();

  bool _isButtonEnabled = false;
  //final _controller = TextEditingController();
  bool isConfirm=false;
  check (BuildContext context){
    if(fNameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
        lNameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
        nickNameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
        phoneController.text.isNotEmpty){
      setState(() {
        _isButtonEnabled = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isButtonEnabled = false;
      });
    }
  }
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /*   double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;*/

    return Scaffold(


      body: SafeArea(

        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [


            _signUp(),

          ],


        ),

      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: MaterialButton(
                height: 44,
                onPressed: () {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
                color:   _isButtonEnabled ? Color(0xFF2A3476) : Color(0x201E1E99),
                elevation: 0,
                highlightElevation: 0,
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                    "Next",
                    style: TextStyle(color: m_fillColor,fontSize: 18,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600  ,
                      fontFamily: "regular",),
                  ),

                ),
              ),


            ),
          ],

        ),


      ),
  
    );

  }


  Widget _signUp() {
    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Color(0xFF2A3476),
            Color(0xFF2A3476),
          ],
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
        ),
      ),
       child: Form(
    key: formKey,

    child: Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 36.0, horizontal: 24.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Create Account",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 34.0,fontFamily: "medium",
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                    ),
                  ),
                  /*  SizedBox(
                   height: 10.0,
                 ),*/
                  /*      Text(
                   "Enter to a beautiful world",
                   style:  TextStyle(
                     color: Colors.white,
                     fontSize: 20.0,
                     fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,

                   ),
                 )*/
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Hello, sign up to",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 29,
                        fontFamily: "regular",
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "continue",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 29,
                        fontFamily: "regular",
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'First Name',
                      style:
                      TextStyle(  fontSize: 15,
                        fontFamily: "regular",),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 12.0,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                      controller: fNameController,
                      onChanged: (val){
                        check(context);
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                          hintText: "",
                        /*  prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                            color: Colors.grey[600],
                          )*/),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Last Name',
                      style:
                      TextStyle(

                          fontSize: 15,
                        fontFamily: "regular",
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 12.0,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      controller: lNameController,
                      onChanged: (val){
                        check(context);
                      },
                      /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,

                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                          hintText: "",
                       /*   prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                            color: Colors.grey[600],
                          )*/),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Nick Name',
                      style:
                      TextStyle(  fontSize: 15,
                        fontFamily: "regular",),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 12.0,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/

                      controller: nickNameController,
                      onChanged: (val){
                        check(context);
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                          hintText: "",
                          /*prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                            color: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                          )*/),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Mobile Number',
                      style:
                      TextStyle(  fontSize: 15,
                        fontFamily: "regular",),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 12.0,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: phoneController,
                      onChanged: (val){
                        check(context);
                      },
                      maxLength: 10,
                     /* validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter some text';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },*/
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                      /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                        filled: true,

                        fillColor: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                        hintText: "077xxxxxxx",

                      ),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),



/*
                    Container(    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: MaterialButton(
                              height: 44,
                              onPressed: () {
                                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                              },
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
                              color:   _isButtonEnabled ? Color(0xFF2A3476) : Color(0x201E1E99),
                              elevation: 2,
                              highlightElevation: 0,
                              child: Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Next",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: m_fillColor,fontSize: 18,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600  ,
                                      fontFamily: "regular",),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),

                    ),*/
                  /*  Container(
                      child: Container(

                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                  offset: Offset(2, 4),
                                  blurRadius: 5,
                                  spreadRadius: 2)
                            ],
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                colors: [
                                  Color(0xFF2A3476),
                                  Color(0xFF2A3476)
                                ])),
                        child: Text(
                          'Next',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),

                        ),

                      ),

                    ),*/

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        RichText(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                            TextSpan(
                                text: "Already have an account?",
                                style: TextStyle(color: m_titleColor,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontFamily: "regular")),
                            TextSpan(
                                text: " Sign in",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color:  Color(0xFF2A3476),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    fontFamily: "medium")),
                          ]),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),  SizedBox(
                      height:100.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),

    ),
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: can you please tell what is the expected output. I am unable to understand the problem

Comment: @anirudh Hello there, I added image description, do you have any idea or solution  ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Column inside Container for Button and Text.

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Column(
     children: [
     // first row
      Row(children: [
   Expanded(
          child: MaterialButton(
            height: 44,
            onPressed: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
            },
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
            color:   _isButtonEnabled ? Color(0xFF2A3476) : Color(0x201E1E99),
            elevation: 0,
            highlightElevation: 0,
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                "Next",
                style: TextStyle(color: m_fillColor,fontSize: 18,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600  ,
                  fontFamily: "regular",),
              ),

            ),
          ),


        ),
      ])
               //second row
                  Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    RichText(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                        TextSpan(
                            text: "Already have an account?",
                            style: TextStyle(color: m_titleColor,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontFamily: "regular")),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: " Sign in",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color:  Color(0xFF2A3476),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                fontFamily: "medium")),
                      ]),
                    )
                  ],
                ), ],)
          ),
```

Comment: Where is to added this? after  body: SafeArea() ??

Comment: Add it as a widget to your "bottomNavigationBar: "

Comment: Hi added new update after my form not display, bottom  going to top

Comment: I added ,but look at this  https://ibb.co/vLJ9BX8 , form section not showing and boom going to top

Comment: Wow, can you show your code, after update?

Comment: hete the code  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kMo-JCWHb-jT9l8GIXPB79KzMJtm11E2IueBr7IDOfE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I changed your body, try it

Comment: i added nothing happened , same issue